# Elasticsearch: Bulk request throws error in Elasticsearch 6.1.1

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, bulk-load

I recently upgraded to Elasticsearch version 6.1.1 and now I can't bulk index documents from a JSON file. When I do it inline, it works fine. Here are the contents of the document:

```
{"index" : {}}
{"name": "Carlson Barnes", "age": 34}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Sheppard Stein","age": 39}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Nixon Singleton","age": 36}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Sharron Sosa","age": 33}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Kendra Cabrera","age": 24}
{"index":{}}
{"name": "Young Robinson","age": 20}
```

When I run this command,

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/subscribers/ppl/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @customers_full.json
```

I get this error:

```
"error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
  },
  "status" : 400
```

It works fine if I send the data inline and in Elasticsearch 5.x. I tried adding newlines as well as the newline character to the end of the file. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Add **empty** line at the end of the JSON file and save the file and then try to run the below command

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/subscribers/ppl/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @customers_full.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Comment: it was so simple, I was trying to add a new line character to command itself :| ..whereas it clearly says '*request* must be terminated by a new line' (y)

Comment: I added the new line but still the issue is showing

Comment: It worked as I added a newline to the json + used `--data-binary` parameter instead of `-d` or `--data`. Adding a newline alone doesn't help.

Comment: Where to create@customers_full.json file?

Comment: You can create anywhere in the file system. But you need to execute the above command from the same location of the JSON file.

Answer (score 26):

As the document says: 
use the `--data-binary` flag instead of plain `-d`

**`-d` doesn’t preserve newlines** and **doesn't format the json**.

I faced this problem because of **JSON formatting**.

Comment: This answer REALLY needs to upvoted to go to the top.  `--data-binary` is indeed different from `-d` even on Mac.  I had thought that binary mode ONLY made a difference in windows platform!

Answer (score 8):

The error is pretty clear:

```
The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]
```

So you simply need to add a newline at the end of your `customers_full.json` file and you'll be ok.

Comment: I did that. I added a newline. I tried adding the newline character, still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the same thing against ES 6.1.3 and it worked perfectly

Comment: Instead of `-d` you should try to use `--data-binary`

Comment: It's something like this https://gist.github.com/Katniss394/f5b44ae76df85246118b3e030e6f8680

Comment: well, somehow an explicit new line is missing at the end of your file, we should see a complete empty line as the last line of your document

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same issue and spent hours adding and removing newlines before somebody pointed out I mis-typed the file name... So note that curl will throw the same error if the file is not actually present, making this super-confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when working with **Elasticsearch 7.3**.

**Here's how I solved it.**

1. Locate the `.json` file, say `products.json` file.
2. Double click to open the `.json` file in your text editor.
3. Scroll to the end of the `.json` file and then press the ENTER key on your keyboard.
4. Close the `.json` file. This will create a new line at the end of `.json` file.
5. Go back to your terminal and run the command below.

N/B: For the command below, the `.json` file name is `products.json` which I am importing to `http://localhost:9200/ecommerce/product`

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ecommerce/product/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@products.json"
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using postman to make requests to ElasticSearch

> Just press enter to create an empty new line!

And voila, problem solved

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "localhost:9200/bank/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@C:\Program Files\Elastic\Elasticsearch\7.2.0\accounts.json"
```

Answer (score 3):

I just forgot to add an `@` symbol before file name like this

```
--data-binary "@products.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to open json file and then go to the end of the file ( Ctrl+end) and then please Enter to break a new line.

Comment: wow! u just saved my life!!!

Answer (score 2):

Press Enter end of the line inside the JSON file and run the command again.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customers/personal/_bulk?pretty&refresh' --data-binary @"generated.json"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem running on Windows 10, using ElasticSearch 7.5.1.

I tried all the answers; none of them worked. I was certain I had a newline at the end of my file.

To get it to work, I had to ensure the file I was uploading was using UNIX end-of-line characters (0A only, no 0D), and also the encoding had to be UTF-8.

[image: ElasticSearch Bulk Fail]

Using Notepad++, you can edit the metadata of the file.

[image: Update EOL]

[image: Update Encoding]

Finally some good news:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `--data-binary` instead of `-d` in your curl request. Please see: [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was only due to the wrong file name.
I have used customer_full.json in command whereas the file was named customer_full in my file system (without the extension).

So in my case,this command worked for me:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/customers/personal/_bulk?pretty&refresh' --data-binary @"customer_full"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue on windows using elastic 7.9.1 When I used below CURL command.

```sh
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/accounts/docs/_bulk?filter_path=items.*.error --data-binary  "@textoutES.json"  >> erroredAtES.json"
```

I tried to manually add Newline at the end of the file but did not work.

I have created my JSON by extracting data from MySQL database like below to make sure my records should end with LINE FEED and CARRIAGE RETURN.

Then, it is working for me:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('{"index":{"_id":"',id,'"}}\r\n',request_data,'\r\n') reqestData FROM cards
```

More importantly you End-of-File should have a carriage-return and Line-Feed (CRLF)if you are using windows. Also if any line in JSON contains a CR but no LF then you will get parsing exception `Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@2d5ed2ca`

[Windows CRLF and EOF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65UX7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for a hot minute. Mine was caused by a space in my curl request between the `--data` and the `-binary` and gave the same error - `must end with new line [\\n]}`.

So double-check that in the curl req it's `--data-binary` not `--data - binary`

Answer (score 1):

When I use `/Users/myName/file.json` the question show, but when I use `@/Users/myName/file.json` it works.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my local set-up.

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/customer/personal/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @"generated.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you do that if you are not using a data-file? I am having the issue but not sending data from a file.

```
const data1 = {
    "amount" : "100",
    "@timestamp" : `${UTC_timestamp}`,
    "transaction_attributes" : {
    "channel" : "channel-foobarbaz",
    "session_id" : "session-1234",
    "information" : "iinformation-foobarbaznformation-foobarbaz"
    },
    "currency" : {
    "currency_description" : "my currency description",
    },
    "external_timestamp" : "2021-12-03T11:22:55.206229500Z" };

  
// execute a post
let res = http.post(url,JSON.stringify(data1),params);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. The file ends with new line (\n).
2. The new line is using Unix eol (LF) and not mac or windows eol.
3. When specifying the file name in the curl command, make sure "@" was added before the file name.