# Unable to bulk insert docs into elastic search index: "Illegal Argument Exception: bulk request must be terminated by newline"

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl

I want to insert the docs contained my `my_docs.json` into my elasticsearch index. My json file looks like this:

```
{"_index":"twitter","_type":"_doc","_id":"v8XSJ2cB_TizemYYi5mW","_score":1,"_source":{"user":"me","c":"2018-11-18T17:16:08.953Z","content":"this is cool stuff"}}

{"_index":"twitter","_type":"_doc","_id":"x8XbJ2cB_TizemYYxZmf","_score":1,"_source":{"user":"you","c":"2018-11-18T17:26:13.634Z","content":"this is some other cool stuff"}}
```

I tried: `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_bulk?pretty&refresh' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @my_docs.json`

where `twitter` is my index.

I got an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I added a '\n' to the end of the file, but the problem persisted and I got the same error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579980/bulk-request-throws-error-in-elasticsearch-6-1-1 ?

Comment: It seems like you might need to specify the content type as data/binary.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "localhost:9200/{index}/{type}/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@my_docs.json"
```

Note: The json file should have content in following format for the above to work:

```
{"index":{"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"1"}}
{"field1":"field 1 data 1","field2":11}
{"index":{"_index":"my_index","_type":"_doc","_id":"2"}}
{"field1":"field 1 data 2","field2":21}`
```

Each document above is represent by two lines. First line indicates where to index and what is the document id. The next line is actual data of the doc.