# Bulk request on ElasticSearch returns the message "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline"

Tags: json, rest, elasticsearch

I am aware that there are already similar questions on StackOverflow, but none of them fixes my current problem.

I am using `ElasticSearch 6.7.0`, and I am currently working through its tutorial. Currently, I am stuck at [this step](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-explore-data.html), which requires me to [download](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/src/test/resources/accounts.json?raw=true) some sample data stored inside a file `accounts.json`. Here is a small snippet of the file:

```
{"index":{"_id":"988"}}
{"account_number":988,"balance":17803,"firstname":"Lucy","lastname":"Castro","age":34,"gender":"F","address":"425 Fleet Walk","employer":"Geekfarm","email":"lucycastro@geekfarm.com","city":"Mulino","state":"VA"}
{"index":{"_id":"990"}}
{"account_number":990,"balance":44456,"firstname":"Kelly","lastname":"Steele","age":35,"gender":"M","address":"809 Hoyt Street","employer":"Eschoir","email":"kellysteele@eschoir.com","city":"Stewartville","state":"ID"}
{"index":{"_id":"995"}}
{"account_number":995,"balance":21153,"firstname":"Phelps","lastname":"Parrish","age":25,"gender":"M","address":"666 Miller Place","employer":"Pearlessa","email":"phelpsparrish@pearlessa.com","city":"Brecon","state":"ME"}
```

The file is saved inside the path `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json`.

I ran the following command, **as instructed in the tutorial**:

> PS C:\Users\Me\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe -H
>   "Content-Type: applicati lhost:9200/bank/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh"
>   --data-binary "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json"

I received this error message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

To fix this, I went to the end of the file and inserted a new line by pressing `Enter`. However, the same error message appeared when I ran the command again.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Dumb question but did you save the file after adding a newline at the end?

Comment: @Val Yup, I did!

Comment: Use  "@C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json" instead of  "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the `accounts.json` file to the same directory from which I am running `curl.exe`, and executed this command:

> .\curl.exe -H "Content-Type: applicati
>   lhost:9200/bank/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary
>   "@accounts.json"

This time, the bulk request was successful.

For those facing similar issues, remember to insert a new line at the end of the file by pressing `Enter`. If that doesn't work, try moving your file into another directory. The error message "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline" can be **misleading** -- your file might not be malformatted at all; perhaps it simply cannot be located or accessed for various reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Use "@C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json" instead of "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json"

i.e.

```
\curl.exe -H "Content-Type: applicati lhost:9200/bank/_doc/_bulk?pretty&refresh" --data-binary "@C:\Users\Me\Desktop\accounts.json"
```

Comment: The use of `--data-binary` over `--data` fixed things for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the EOL characters and Encoding of your file, as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59791215/2726844