# C# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync() fails, even though the exact same request is accepted when made through PostMan

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I have found similar questions both here as well as on [the Elastic discussion forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/), but unfortunately none of the answers helped.

I am currently using `ElasticSearch 7.0`.

I want to make a bulk request to my ElasticSearch server. My JSON file contains information that looks something like this:

```
{ "index": { "_index": "website", "_id": "link1" }}
{ "label":    "Link1" }
```

Each line is terminated by an `LF` line break, and there is also an additional `LF` line break at the end of the document.

In C#, here is how I make a POST request for my bulk data:

`HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"http://127.0.0.1:9200/website/_bulk", jsonDocumentContents);`

And yet I keep seeing this error message:

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"},"status":400}`

How can I fix this error?

**UPDATE:**

A short description of how I read the JSON document contents into the `jsonDocumentContents` variable: The JSON document was stored inside a zipped folder, so retrieving it requires unzipping:

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zippedFolderStream);
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    string jsonDocumentContents = new StreamReader(entry.Open()).ReadToEnd();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync($"http://127.0.0.1:9200/website/_bulk", jsonDocumentContents);
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I just made a bulk request with the exact same contents using PostMan, and the request was successful. However, the error message persists when I make the same bulk request in C# using `httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(...)`.

Comment: The question is probably how do you read the file content into the `jsonDocumentContents` variable?

Comment: @Val Thank you for your comment. I have updated my post to include information that answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk request throws error in elasticsearch 6.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579980/bulk-request-throws-error-in-elasticsearch-6-1-1)

Comment: @stop-cran There is already an empty line at the end of my file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working by changing my code to the following:

```
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zippedFolderStream);
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    string jsonDocumentContents = new StreamReader(entry.Open()).ReadToEnd();
    StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonDocumentContents, Encoding.ASCII, mediaType: "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"http://127.0.0.1:9200/website/_bulk", content);
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Notice that I am using `HttpClient.PostAsync()` instead of `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync()`, with a `StringContent` instance that specifies `"application/json"` as its media type.

I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs) for `HttpClient`, and noticed that a new instance of `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` is created every time `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` is called.

Since my `POST` requests are successful when I make them through PostMan, the issue must be caused by how `PostAsJsonAsync()` is implemented. I suspect, but have not verified, that the problem is due to the default properties in the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` class.

To circumvent the problem I decided to use `Http.PostAsync()` with a correctly-configured `StringContent` instance.

Lo and behold, I can now send bulk requests to my ElasticSearch server using C#.

Comment: `PostAsJsonAsync` will *serialize whatever you give it to JSON*. So if you pass in a string like `{ first:0 }\n{ second:1 }`, it will serialize the string to JSON as such: `"{ first:0 }\\n{ second:1 }"` and then send it. When ES gets it and deserializes it, it only would see a single JSON string, not a series of JSON objects.

Comment: pretty sure it was related to some C# method doing some smart-ass conversion. glad you figured it out

Comment: Man! Wish I found this post earlier. WTF MS 4 hours wasted cause of this PostAsJsonAsync bs!!!