# _score for nested documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to make _score for nested documents and for thouse parent?
For example:
Parent _doc title: "car"
nested docs: "red", "blue"
user searching for red car and the score for parent should be 0.5, and for nested doc "red" 1, for "blue" 0.5 or 0
and if user searching "black car" parent doc should have _score = 0.5 and nested docs may have 0.5 or 0.
Is it possible?
I need it to give to user a link to a page with a parent doc, or with a nested doc.

Comment: With elasticsearch search you get back one score per document. So, basically your parent documents will be scored, do you want the score from the nested matches to be added to the score of the parent or do you want the nested documents to be returned as separate documents with separate scores? Really confused about what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: i dont want to separate them. I want that elastic returns a score for nested docs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the score of the nested documents by using `inner_hits` and you can disable effect of these scores on the parent scores by wrapping the nested query into constant scorer with boost 0. You can also wrap the parent query into `constant_score` query in order to remove the effect of IDF and document length normalization. If you combine this all together you will get something like this:

```
DELETE test
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "item": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "color": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"item": "car", "attributes":[{ "color": "red" }, {"color": "blue"}]}
{"index": {}}
{"item": "car", "attributes":[{ "color": "black" }]}

POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "simple_query_string": {
                "query": "red car",
                "fields": ["item"]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "inner_hits": {},
            "query": {
              "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                  "simple_query_string": {
                    "query": "red car",
                    "fields": ["attributes.*"]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "boost": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The elements `_score` in the response correspond to the scores that you are looking for.

Comment: trying to make your request, and nothing found:
{ 
"took": 86,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": { 
"total": 1,
"successful": 1,
"skipped": 0,
"failed": 0
},
"hits": { 
"total": { 
"value": 0,
"relation": "eq"
},
"max_score": null,
"hits": [ 
]
}
}

Comment: Have you tried running my entire example? Does it work? If not, which version did you run it on?

Comment: i did, version 8.6.2

Comment: When i'm doing bulk request, i have an error:
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"
  },
  "status": 400
}

Comment: So, whatever you are using to run this commands doesn't send `\n` at the end of the request body. The script above was written to work in Kibana Dev Console (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html) which I highly recommend for working with elasticsearch. If you run it using curl you need to use `--data-binary` flag instead of `-d` or `--data` for the bulk request. For other clients, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579980/elasticsearch-bulk-request-throws-error-in-elasticsearch-6-1-1

Comment: I use elasticsearch tools for chrome

Comment: ok, now it works. But, how can i make a simple search query "red car" and see result with inner_hits?

Comment: I have updated the query to work with "red car". If there are any matches in the attributes, they will show in the inner_hits. If match is only with the main record, the inner hits will be empty. I hope that helps.

Comment: Put the whole nested part into filter instead of a should clause.